# Why does creating new branches in Xcode9 always fail with "not a valid branch name"?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode9-beta, xcode9

Whenever I try to create a new branch, it says: The name "MY-BRANCH-NAME" is not a valid branch name. I am adding the steps I performed while trying to create a new branch.

Why is this happening?

P.s.- There are no uncommitted changes and everything is pushed to github repository.

[image: first step]

[image: second step]

[image: The problem]

Comment: This seems to be a bug, file a radar.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I have tried that and it works. I was just wondering why the same wasn't working with Xcode.

Comment: I don't know - but knowing this type of UI more than likely it's a bug with xCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.  Looks like an xcode bug.

xcode Version 9.0 beta 3 (9M174d)

I exited xcode, ran up sourcetree and created the new branch, loaded up xcode again and all appears fine.
I also replicated the issue with a brand new spritekit game project.

Raised a bug report with apple:
https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=33497210

Comment: Appears to be fixed in the latest version of xcode (Version 9.0 beta 4 (9M189t)) that was released yesterday 24/7.  I downloaded it today, opened the same sample project that was previously failing and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with your git UI? are you able to get the command line working. simply type in: "git checkout -b new-branch-name" and it should work unless you include some illegal characters in there. The cause is more than likely a bug in the particular UI of git application that you are using.